# "Address can not be validated" error when purchasing Australian SMS numbers via API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We cannot complete the process for purchasing an Australian mobile number through the Twilio API.

These are our steps:

1. Get Available Numbers (we can create a AU mobile number successfully)
2. Create Address (Error)
3. Incoming phone number (Unable to get to this step due to the error in step 2)

We are calling the AvailablePhoneNumber Mobile resource
https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/availablephonenumber-mobile-resource and this api returns us the AU SMS number successfully.

But when we call the IncomingPhoneNumber resource
https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource this api is returning an error:

Error : Phone number Requires and Address but the "AddressSid" parameter was empty.

We were advised by support to use any random address, which, for example we tried:

So when we use this, using a random address:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Addresses.json"
--data-urlencode "CustomerName=XXX"
--data-urlencode "Street=24 Outlook Crescent"
--data-urlencode "City=Bardon"
--data-urlencode "Region=Queensland"
--data-urlencode "PostalCode=4065"
--data-urlencode "IsoCountry=AU"
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

It comes back with an error "this address can not be validated".

If we do the same with a request for US SMS numbers there is no issue. It is solely with Australian SMS mobile numbers.

See above for our process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an valid address from anywhere in the world as mentioned on this [regulations page](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/guidelines/au/regulatory).

I'd recommend using the [console UI](https://console.twilio.com/) to create this address once and to get the "AddressSid" which you can then use for all subsequent API calls to purchase mobile phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks, we will have a look at this and try. It may just be the case that we had the region state as the State rather than Oceania. 